# With VueJS, How can I intelligently retain Vuex state between components?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

First, think of a table that has a search, sort, and pagination. Items (rows) have details, which loads a route to show the detail component. Within this detail component, there's another table with a search, sort, and pagination, that of which also has a detail view to drill down further.

I'm using `vuex` to retain the state of *most* components, at least where it makes sense. In this case, the `search query`, `sort`, and `pagination` are all stored in the store. Also keeping in mind, I'm trying to decouple my components as much as possible to make testing easier and provide better maintainability.

Imagine this routing structure:

**/Properties** *Shows a list of property locations*

**/Properties/location/1** *Shows a list of buildings within that location*

**/Properties/location/1/building/1** *Shows a list of offices within that building*

Let's say I'm on the first route, and I search for a location, that of which produces 3 records that match the search query. Great! I click on the first one, view some details... and click Go Back. My search is still intact as it was stored in `vuex` so my state is retained. Perfect.

I navigate away to another route, entirely separate from the locations section, and then navigate back. Yuck, my search is still there. This isn't what I would expect (intuitively), but would expect programmatically.

Here's how I solved it. Please tell me if there's a better way.

In my routes, I always use props, and in my main navigation component, I set it up to pass a clearState property.

So the component has this:

```
props: {
  clearState: {
    type: Boolean,
    default() {
      return false;
    }
  }
},

created() {

  if (this.clearState) {
    this.$store.dispatch("properties/setSearch", "");
  }
  this.$store.dispatch("fetchLocations");       
}
```

And my route in the main navigation menu has this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: "Locations", params: { clearState: true }}">Locations</router-link>
```

This works great. But, I have several layers of detail components as we drill down, so now I feel like I'm getting tightly coupled:

```
created() {

  if (this.clearState) {
    this.$store.dispatch("properties/setSearch", "");
    this.$store.dispatch("buildings/setSearch", "");
    this.$store.dispatch("offices/setSearch", "");
  }
  this.$store.dispatch("fetchLocations");       
}
```

I played around with router guards, but access to `this` within the component isn't immediately available, which slows the request to my API. It also forced me to use meta properties to determine what to and from routes should force the clearing of state.

**My Question**

I've solved my issue, but I have a gut feeling there's a better design pattern out there that I haven't figured out yet.

1. Is my solution prone to unseen error?
2. Is there a better way to do this that I'm obviously missing?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think you can use the Navigation Guards of vue-router to clear that data in store

Comment: @jacky thank you but I'm aware. Not quite the issue but rather a potential design change to get the desired intelligence.